# How to determine Input Output (var length) of RAW hexa data of BTC transaction?

Tags: sha256, bitcoin

For the following with respect to SHA-256 encoding;

```
01000000011e4bf9dc623d942fee4113e077f67204419cb6f841d98ebf250b698cbea8912b000000006b483045022100a7ce3b1d8cc852e625e5da3159131ba7ba071c7a93684f1d3b8d08b6dbc08e82022041ac850772b5877cc8b724f6a7a92709a65a17a52f78419b67304f2481526b79412102e8a1ab43a501a2ab84a14c5ef1a65c15add65f3ec8230e3fb63644a44ac71003ffffffff0200943577000000001976a914aa5604bae61cd60690dd9dec5efbb841668cb19288ac8f933577000000001976a914e33649e455368d536f6003b2908b6299df5fe8bf88ac00000000
```

How can I determine the `Input List (Var length)` and Output `List (Var length)`?

When you have a RAW hexadecimal format (BTC/ SHA-256) for for a transaction, it's decoded and the transaction consist of several serialized elements.

Out of the those how am I able to extract the Input & Output list (var length).

Calculated hash using Bitcoin's hash functions.

Input Encoding = HEX | Hash Function = SHA-256 | Output Encoding = HEX |
w/ Big Endian.

Gave the Input Message, the Message Digest comes out invalid.